# How can I acquire access to my android app's database and context from JUnit test?

Tags: android, junit

I need to test some function, that needs my application's database and context.

I used to implement my testcase like this:

```
// TestCase is in the same package with tested module
package com.ircos.andromeda.utils;
...
// database operation classes
import com.ircos.andromeda.database.MeasurementDbAdapter; 
import com.ircos.andromeda.database.SessionDbAdapter;
import com.ircos.andromeda.database.domain.Measurement;
import com.ircos.andromeda.database.domain.Session;
import com.ircos.andromeda.exceptions.ExportException;

public class SessionExportHelperTestCase extends AndroidTestCase {
...
```

So, I thought context, retrieved by getContext() should return my application's context and I'd be able to use the database just like from application itself.

But I failed. What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void setUp() {
    sessionDbAdapter.open(); // exception fires here!
```

...

```
public void open() throws SQLiteException {
    if (isOpen())
        return;

    this.open(new DatabaseManagementHelper(this.ctx)); // context is null!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you have not assigned `getContext()` to `this.ctx`, and so `this.ctx` remains `null`.

Comment: Thanks, you re right. I'm completely new to android, so I assumed, that test case's context would be same to context of application I tested :\ Now I use ApplicationTestCase to acquire right one. And I use now test application's resources to store some reference data for tests, and stucked upon how to get the context of test application%) getSystemContext() did not help. Can you help me? I'd place this as separate question.

Comment: `getContext()` of an `AndroidTestCase` will give you a context suitable for testing resources.